# How do I get the urlopen command in Python to give up and move on?

Tags: python, timeout, urlopen

I'm working on a script in `Python 2.7` that downloads web pages.  Most of the time, everything proceeds as planned.  Given that this script has thousands of web pages to download, there will inevitably be a few times when things don't work out.  The script gives up and moves on in the event of a `URLError` or an `HTTPError`, but there are times when everything just hangs, and it takes manually hitting `Ctrl-Z` or `Ctrl-C` to stop this.  The code in question:

```
    f = urlopen (url)
    local_file = open (file_name, 'w') # Open local file
    local_file.write (f.read())
    local_file.close ()
```

I've tried `signal.alarm`, but it doesn't always work.  I tried the timeout parameter in urlopen, but this doesn't work.

Is there a reliable way to make sure the script automatically gives up and moves on after a certain number of seconds?  Should I be using something other than urlopen?

Comment: check out this link http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/182555/how-to-set-timeout-for-reading-from-urls-in-urllib#

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using urllib2

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
try:
    f = urlopen (url, timeout=10)
except urllib2.URLError:
    # try again later
```

Answer (score 0):

If your doing http requests, I highly recommend to use the requests python library. You will find it much easier to use and much more powerfull. It can be found here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

To install and use:

```
$: pip install requests
```

Code to do something like you want

```
import requests

try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    local_file = open(file_name, 'w') # Open local file
    local_file.write(response.content)
    local_file.close()
except requests.ConnectionError:
    pass
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Mark